# программирование на языке awk

Tags: awk

Есть задание:

> Текстовый файл состоит из строк только целых чисел. Количество чисел
>   в строках может быть различным. Найти сумму тех чисел, у которых
>   первое число строки не совпадает с последним числом предыдущей
>   строки.

Понимаю,что нужно создать переменную суммы, приравнять её к 0. Затем нужно в цикле считывать строки...Но как сделать сравнение последнего числа предыдущей строки с первым числом данной  строки?
Нужно как-то сохранять это в переменные или нет?
Еще нужно как-то учесть,что может быть первая строка, у которой нет предыдущей и последняя, у которой нет следующей.
На сколько я понял, должно быть так:
Текстовый документ(входящие данные):

1. 2 6 31 11 19
2. 19 22 63 11 36
3. 6 32 47 133 6
4. 53 86 382 38 79 1
5. 1 0 82 76 8 30 57

Вывод в консоли:

1. 69 (у первой строки нет предыдущей строки)
2. 224 (выведет сумму 3 строки)
3. 639 (сумма четвертой строки)

Comment: Добавление к вопросу: 1) входные данные 2) выходные данные (результат) 3) код автора (пусть и неудачный) повышает шансы получить ответ

Comment: в цикле обрабатывать каждую строку. запоминать последнее число пред. строки и сравнивать, что данная строка начинается с этим числом.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Но я конкретно не знаю как это записать кодом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getnarr(arr, s)
{
    while (arr[s] != "")
        s++

    return s
}

BEGIN {
    filename = "/home/ast/Downloads/documents/gawk/test.txt" # путь к файлу
    i = 0

    while ((getline line < filename) > 0) {
        lines[i] = line
        i++
    }

    close(filename)
    j = 1
    k = 2

    while (j < i && k < i) {
        split(lines[0], fnum, " ", seps)
        split(lines[j], num, " ", seps)
        split(lines[k], num2, " ", seps)

        if (j == 1) {
            fsum = 0

            for (l in fnum)
                fsum += int(fnum[l])

            print fsum
        }

        if (num[(getnarr(num, 1) - 1)] != num2[1]) {
            sum = 0

            for (m in num2)
                sum += int(num2[m])

            print sum
        }

        j++
        k++
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72117/discussion-on-answer-by-ast----awk).